# как скопировать Stream java 8?

Tags: java, java-stream

Нужна функция которая вычисляет мин и макс от `Stream`

```
public static <T> void findMinMax(
            Stream<? extends T> stream,
            Comparator<? super T> order)
```

т.к.Stream допускает вызов только одной терминальной операции,  то так нельзя:

```
Optional<? extends T> min =stream.min(order);
Optional<? extends T> max = stream.max(order);
```

Можно ли как-то "раздвоить" стримы, чтобы операция над 1 не влияло на 2-й?

```
    Object[] mass = new Object[2];

    mass[0] = stream;
    mass[1] = stream;

    Stream<? extends T> str1 = (Stream<? extends T>)mass[0];
    Stream<? extends T> str2 = (Stream<? extends T>)mass[1];

    Optional<? extends T> min =str1.min(order);
    Optional<? extends T> max = str2.max( order);
```

так тоже летит исключение.

---

Допустим я сделал стрим из элементов от 1...10

```
Stream<Integer> str =   Stream.<Integer>iterate(1, n-> n+1)
                              .limit(10);
```

и компаратор  `Comparator<Integer> comp = (Integer o1, Integer o2) ->  o1.compare(o1, o2);`

передаю это в метод:

```
 public static <T> void findMinMax(
                Stream<? extends T> stream,
                Comparator<? super T> order)

 {

    Object[] mass = new Object[2];
            Stream str = stream;
            mass[0] = null; // max
            mass[1] = null; // min
            if(stream !=null){
                stream.forEach(t-> {
                if(order.compare(t, (T) mass[0])>0) mass[0] = t;
                if(order.compare(t, (T) mass[1])<0) mass[1] = t;
                });
   }
             Optional<? extends T> min =(Optional<? extends T>) Optional.of(mass[0]);
             Optional<? extends T> max = (Optional<? extends T>) Optional.of(mass[1]);
```

стандартный метод `Integer.compare` с `null` не сравнивается и так вылетает `NullPointerException`, инициализировать массивы нулями сразу не могу, т.к. передаваемый параметр `Stream<? extends T> stream` не только `Integer` может быть, как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Как я понимаю это нельзя сделать принципиально. Но вдруг кто-то знает хак. Или вы можете пройтись руками по стриму и найти в нём минимальный и максимальный элемента "руками".

Comment: reduce делайте в Pair<T,T>, в котором сравнивайте левую с левой и правую с правой.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static <T> Pair<T, T> findMinMax(
        Stream<? extends T> stream,
        Comparator<? super T> order, Pair<T, T> identity) {
    return stream.reduce(
            identity, 
            (pair, t) -> {
            T min = order.compare(pair.getKey(), t) < 0 ? pair.getKey() : t;
            T max = order.compare(pair.getValue(), t) > 0 ? pair.getValue() : t;
            return new Pair<>(min, max);
        }, 
            (p1, p2) -> {
            T min = order.compare(p1.getKey(), p2.getKey()) < 0 ? p2.getKey() : p1.getKey();
            T max = order.compare(p1.getValue(), p2.getValue()) > 0 ? p1.getValue() : p1.getValue();
            return new Pair<>(min, max);
        }
    );
}
```

Какой-то такой вот кошмар..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pair<Integer, Integer> identity = new Pair<>(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    Comparator<Integer> comp = (Integer o1, Integer o2) ->  o1.compare(o1, o2);
    Pair<Integer, Integer> p = Example.findMinMax(s, comp, identity);
    System.out.println(p); // 1..10
}
```

PS: альтернативная имплементация без identity по совету @TagirValeev :

```
public static <T> Pair<T, T> findMinMax(
        Stream<? extends T> stream,
        Comparator<? super T> order) {
    return stream.reduce(
            null,
            (pair, t) -> {
                if (pair == null) return new Pair<>(t,t);
                T min = order.compare(pair.getKey(), t) < 0 ? pair.getKey() : t;
                T max = order.compare(pair.getValue(), t) > 0 ? pair.getValue() : t;
                return new Pair<>(min, max);
        },
            (p1, p2) -> {
                if (p1 == null) return p2;
                if (p2 == null) return p1;
                T min = order.compare(p1.getKey(), p2.getKey()) < 0 ? p2.getKey() : p1.getKey();
                T max = order.compare(p1.getValue(), p2.getValue()) > 0 ? p1.getValue() : p1.getValue();
                return new Pair<>(min, max);}
    );
}
```

Comment: сигнатура должна такой же остаться

Comment: @ketchyn но куда тогда возвращать или присваивать min/max? по вашей сигнатуре должны быть какие-то сайдэффекты..

Comment: Без `indentity` в целом легко обойтись. Хоть бы и `null` в качестве `identity` использовать и проверочки вставить типа `if(ttPair == null) return new Pair<>(t, t)` в accumulator и `if(ttPair == null) return ttPair2; if(ttPair2 == null) return ttPair;` в combiner (так и сравнений меньше). Ну и зря вы, конечно, анонимный класс вместо лямбды вставили.

Comment: Да, конечно можно было обойтись без identity, но это усложнило бы пример лишним мусором. Лямбду поправлю, да.

Answer (score 1):

Желание сделать два стрима из одного убивает утверждение из документации по интерфейсу `java.util.Stream`:

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal
>   stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked"
>   streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or
>   multiple traversals of the same stream.

Видимо поэтому в интернете ничего похожего сходу не находится.

В принципе, можно сделать вычисление через `Stream.peek`, но для этого нужно или сделать последовательный поток, через `Stream.sequential`, или самому думать над потокобезопасностью, примерно так:

```
AtomicReference<String> max = new AtomicReference<String>();
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();

System.out.println( 
        Arrays.stream( new String[] {"one", "two", "абракадабра", "ten", "cat" } )
            .peek( candidate -> max.updateAndGet( current -> {
                if ( current == null ) return candidate;
                return comparator.compare( current, candidate ) >= 0 ? current : candidate;
            } ) )
            .min( comparator ) + " " + Optional.ofNullable( max.get() )
    );
// вывод: Optional[cat] Optional[абракадабра]
```

Для числовых примитивов в библиотеке есть коллектор `java.util.IntSummaryStatistics` (а так же `double` и `long` версии), из которого можно получить минимум, максимум, среднее и количество элементов в потоке. Я попытался написать свой такой же, но для объектов:

```
public class ObjectSummaryStatistics<T> implements Consumer<T> {
    int count = 0;
    T min = null;
    T max = null;

    final Comparator<T> comparator;

    public static <T> Collector<T, ObjectSummaryStatistics<T>, ObjectSummaryStatistics<T>> collector( final Comparator<T> comparator ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( comparator, "Must supply comparator." );

        return Collector.<T, ObjectSummaryStatistics<T>, ObjectSummaryStatistics<T>>of(
                () -> new ObjectSummaryStatistics<T>( comparator ),
                ObjectSummaryStatistics::accept, 
                ObjectSummaryStatistics::combine,
                ObjectSummaryStatistics::finish,
                Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH
            );
    }


    public ObjectSummaryStatistics( Comparator<T> comparator ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( comparator, "Must supply comparator." );
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept( T value ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( value, "This collector does not accept nulls" );
        if ( count == 0 ) {
            min = value;
            max = value;
        } else {
            updateMin(value);
            updateMax(value);
        }
        count += 1;
    }

    public ObjectSummaryStatistics<T> combine( ObjectSummaryStatistics<T> other ) {
        if ( other.count > 0 ) {
            if ( this.count == 0 ) {
                this.min = other.min;
                this.max = other.max;
                this.count = other.count;
            } else {
                updateMin( other.min );
                updateMax( other.max );
                this.count += other.count;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public ObjectSummaryStatistics<T> finish() {
        return this;
    }


    private void updateMax(T value) {
        if ( comparator.compare( value, max ) > 0 ) {
            max = value;
        }
    }

    private void updateMin(T value) {
        if ( comparator.compare( value, min ) < 0 ) {
            min = value;
        }
    }

    public int count() {
        return count;
    }

    public Optional<T> max() {
        // если count > 0, у нас должен быть непустой максимум
        return count > 0 ? Optional.of( max ) : Optional.empty();
    }

    public Optional<T> min() {
        return count > 0 ? Optional.of( min ) : Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObjectSummaryStatistics [count=" + count + ", min=" + min + ", max=" + max + "]";
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
    System.out.println( 
            Arrays.stream( new String[] {"one", "two", "абракадабра", "ten", "cat" } )
                .collect( ObjectSummaryStatistics.collector( Comparator.<String>naturalOrder() ) )
        );
// вывод: ObjectSummaryStatistics [count=5, min=cat, max=абракадабра]

    System.out.println( 
            Arrays.stream( new String[] {} )
                .collect( ObjectSummaryStatistics.collector( Comparator.<String>naturalOrder() ) )
        );
// вывод: ObjectSummaryStatistics [count=0, min=null, max=null]
```

`null` в потоке запрещен, чтобы убрать неоднозначность при получении значений (`Stream.min` тоже с `null` не работает).

Comment: Я бы, наверно, возвращал `ObjectSummaryStatistics` всегда, а вот у него методы `min` и `max` уже пусть `Optional<T>` возвращают (count = 0 — вполне валидное значение). Ну и да, нуллы запретить совсем.

Answer (score 0):

Я только что бился над похожей задачей. Да, хочется у стрима вызывать методы `min` и `max`, когда становится ясно, что только получится вызвать только один из двух, появляется желание раздвоить стрим. Но в этом и подвох, как я понимаю. Постановка задачи такова, чтобы мы учились находить решения не только в лоб, но и искать не очевидные пути. В конце концов, выбрать минимальное и макимальное значения из любого набора можно несколькими способами.

Я решил задачу так: отсортировал стрим, преобразовал его в массив, и взял минимальный элемент из начала, а максимальный из конца. Вот код, может неоптимальный, но тестирующая система его приняла:

```
public static <T> void findMinMax(
    Stream<? extends T> stream,
    Comparator<? super T> order,
    BiConsumer<? super T, ? super T> minMaxConsumer) {

Object[] items = stream.sorted(order).toArray();

if (items.length == 0) {
    minMaxConsumer.accept( null, null);    
} else {
    T min = (T) items[0];
    T max = (T) items[items.length - 1];

   minMaxConsumer.accept( min, max);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Решение преподавателя курса:

```
public static <T> void findMinMax(
        Stream<? extends T> stream,
        Comparator<? super T> order,
        BiConsumer<? super T, ? super T> minMaxConsumer) {

    MinMaxFinder<T> minMaxFinder = new MinMaxFinder<>(order);
    stream.forEach(minMaxFinder);
    minMaxConsumer.accept(minMaxFinder.min, minMaxFinder.max);
}

private static class MinMaxFinder<T> implements Consumer<T> {

    private final Comparator<? super T> order;
    T min;
    T max;

    private MinMaxFinder(Comparator<? super T> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T t) {
        if (min == null || order.compare(t, min) < 0) {
            min = t;
        }
        if (max == null || order.compare(max, t) < 0) {
            max = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Остальным ответам можно простить изобретение велосипеда за то, что даны они четыре года назад. Но вы-то зачем это делаете? Минимальное и максимальное значение можно [получить с помощью summaryStatistics](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809157/204271), а "раздвоить стрим" с помощью [teeing collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)).