# Можно ли из одного Stream достать сразу и min() и max()?

Tags: java, java-stream, max, java-9, min

Пусть есть `IntStream`, возможно ли получить из него допустим массив или лист, в котором будут 2 значения `min` и `max` стрима? Либо можно ли вообще каким-то образом вызвать терминальный метод на стрим больше 1 раза?

Answer (score 11):

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.range(1, 100)
                                      .summaryStatistics();

int min = stats.getMin();
int max = stats.getMax();
```

Comment: Да, так тоже можно :)

Comment: пустой stream покажет min = 2147483647, а max = -2147483648:) надо выполнить проверку min <= max, чтобы убедится, что steam не пустой, что есть из чего выбирать и min и max

Comment: Зачем `min<=max`, если есть `getCount()`?

Comment: @vp_arth Действительно можно. Не подумал, что может быть `getCount`. Так же как не подумал о том, что для извлечения только лишь min и max, можно попутно насобирать и кучу другой, бесполезной в данном случае, статистики:) Хотя это может быть даже оптимальнее, быстрее самодельного `collec`. Кто знает, кто знает...

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать коллектор, находящий минимальный и максимальный элемент. Вообще рекомендую способ с IntSummaryStatistics, но коллектор можно сделать. 
Коллектор:

```
static<T, R> Collector<T, ?, Optional<R>> minMax(
        Comparator<? super T> comparator,
        BiFunction<? super T, ? super T, ? extends R> finisher){

    class Accumulator{
        T min;
        T max;

        boolean present;

        void add(T value){
            if(present){
                if(comparator.compare(value, min) <0) min= value;
                if(comparator.compare(value, max) >0) max= value;

            }else {
                min=max=value;
                present=true;
            }
        }

        Accumulator combiner(Accumulator other){
            if(!other.present) return this;
            if(!present) return other;
            if(comparator.compare(other.min, min) <0) min=other.min;
            if(comparator.compare(other.max, max) >0) max=other.max;
            return this;
        }


    }

    return Collector.of(Accumulator::new,
            Accumulator::add,
            Accumulator::combiner,
            accumulator -> accumulator.present
                    ? Optional.of(finisher.apply(accumulator.min, accumulator.max))
                    : Optional.empty());
}
```

Его использование может выглядит вот так:

```
Integer [] arr= IntStream.of(12, 45, 23, 68).
            boxed().
            collect(
                    minMax(
                            Integer::compareTo, (min, max) -> new Integer[] {min, max})).get();
    for (Integer i: arr) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Можно сделать чтоб возвращал List:

```
List<Integer> list =IntStream.of(12, 45, 23, 68).
            boxed().
            collect(
                    minMax(
                            Integer::compareTo, (min, max) -> Arrays.asList(min, max))).get();

    list.iterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет, стрим позволяет пройтись по нему только один раз (а если нижележащий сплитератор выстрелит, то можно и вообще не дойти до конца). Но это не значит, что вы не можете одновременно собирать и максимум, и минимум:

```
private static class Result {
    private Integer minimum;
    private Integer maximum;

    public Integer getMinimum() {
        return minimum;
    }

    public Integer getMaximum() {
        return maximum;
    }

    public synchronized Result update(int value) {
        if (minimum == null || minimum > value) {
            minimum = value;
        }
        if (maximum == null || maximum < value) {
            maximum = value;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public synchronized void combine(Result other) {
        if (other.getMinimum() != null) {
            update(other.getMinimum());
        }
        if (other.getMaximum() != null) {
            update(other.getMaximum());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Result {minimum=" + minimum + ", maximum=" + maximum + "}";
    }
}

public static Result compute(IntStream stream) {
    return stream.collect(Result::new, Result::update, Result::combine);
}
```

Comment: Да, так то можно, имел ввиду чтобы одним стримом и без доп методов. Спасибо за инфу!

Comment: IntStream разве имеет `reduce` такой сигнатуры? там ведь только `int reduce(...)` и `OptionalInt reduce(...)` ничего типа `<R> reduce(...)` вроде нет

Comment: @Sergey почему-то думал, что у всех стримов сигнатуры совпадают, обновил, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот Ваш массив:

```
int[] miniMax = IntStream.range(1, 11).collect(() -> {
    return new int[] { Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE };
}, (t, value) -> {
    if (t[0] > value) t[0] = value;
    if (t[1] < value) t[1] = value;
}, (t, u) -> {
    if (t[0] > u[0]) t[0] = u[0];
    if (t[1] < u[1]) t[1] = u[1];
});

int min = miniMax[0];
int max = miniMax[1];
```

Если попадётся пустой stream, то получится невероятный результат `min == 2147483647` и `max == -2147483648`

Условие, что получено именно то, что надо: `min <= max`